# HockeySDK Warning - How to test crash reporting?

Tags: ios, objective-c, hockeyapp

I got this warning when running my application with HockeyApp integration:

`[HockeySDK] WARNING: Detecting crashes is NOT enabled due to running the app with a debugger attached.`

Crash reports are not sent and no alert is displayed when opening the app again.
Any one have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What issue is there to resolve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has very simple reasons:

If you are running the app with Xcode attached, your app is connected to `lldb`, Xcode's debugger. When `lldb` is attached, it will of course do its job as a debugger and catch any exception or crash that occurs. This means that the crash can never reach the HockeyApp SDK or any other crash reporting SDK while `lldb` is attached at the same time.

The solution is also pretty simple. If you just want to make sure the SDK is integrated properly and will catch crashes, do the following:

1. Do a quick "Build & Run" to install the current version of the app on the simulator or device.
2. Click the "Stop" button in Xcode to stop the debugging session.
3. Manually start the app on the device or simulator by tapping or clicking the app icon.
4. Cause a crash.
5. Restart the app. Now the HockeySDK should process the crash report and show a dialog to approve crash log sending.

One thing to keep in mind: Make sure to not make the app crash immediately after app start as this would not give the SDK enough time to process and send the crash report before crashing again.

Answer (score 1):

Hockey app sdk by default does not send report when a debugger is attached. There is nothing wrong with this.

It will send report when a archive build that release to ur tester cause a crash. I personally think this should and remain as this because you are trying to track crashes from your tester not when you are developing.